# Declare activity in AndroidManifest.xml to use an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I have the following Intent object I'm trying to convey from the fragment SeventhFragment.java to another fragment (SixthFragment.java).

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), SixthFragment.class);
i.putExtra("officeHour", hour);
startActivity(i); // this code is in SeventhFragment.java
```

In SixthFragment.java, I have the following code to try to get this object back:

```
Intent intent = (Intent) getActivity().getIntent(); // this code is in SixthFragment.java.
OfficeHour add = (OfficeHour) intent.getSerializableExtra("officeHour");
```

However, I'm getting an exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
{com.example.app/com.example.app.SixthFragment}; have you declared 
this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I can tell that this means that I need to add an activity declaration  to AndroidManifest.xml, but I can't tell what I should add / how this should be formatted. Just as a note, I've tried looking around for pre-existing questions, I still can't tell what exactly to write in my manifest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `Fragment` always needs to be hosted by an `Activity`. You can't transition between fragments by using an `Intent`. Instead, you could use a `FragmentTransaction` and pass the data as an argument:

```java
// this code is in SeventhFragment's underlying Activity
Fragment f = new SixthFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("officeHour", hour);
f.setArguments(args);

// Execute a transaction to replace SeventhFragment with SixthFragment
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// R.id.myfragment needs to be defined in your Activity's layout resource
ft.replace(R.id.myfragment, f);
ft.commit();
```

You can then retrieve the argument value in the `SixthFragment`'s `onCreateView`:

```java
public class SixthFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OfficeHour add = (OfficeHour) getArguments().getSerializable("officeHour");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could embed `SixthFragment` into its own `Activity` and use an intent to start it.

You can find more information in the official `Fragment` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the Activity layout resource? Where would I find that? Thanks!

Comment: In your project you should find a `src/main/res` or `resources` folder with a `layout` subfolder. There should be a `main_activity.xml` file (or similar) declaring the layout of the corresponding `Activity`. Within this file you can define different components which you can assign a resource id (`android:id`) to. After having created a `<fragment>` component with a proper id (`android:id="@+id/myfragment"`), you can refer to it with `R.id.myfragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Intent is used to start new activity . You can't change fragments using Intent.
To Change fragments.

Try Below links and code to implement fragments.

[fragmnets 1](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/fragment)      [Fragments in Detail](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

```
   FristFragment firstFragmentInstance=new FirstFragment();
    FragmentManager firstFragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction firstFragmentTransaction=firstFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    firstFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_main,firstFragmentInstance,"").commit();
```

And to replace fragments

```
   FristFragment firstFragmentInstance=new FirstFragment();
    FragmentManager firstFragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction firstFragmentTransaction=firstFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    firstFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main,firstFragmentInstance,"first_fragment_tag").addToBackStack(null).commit()
```